# Python not found

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm working on a project in a python virtual environment, the project was started on a pc with python 3.8 installed and consequently python 3.8 was used in the virtual environment, or I had the need to continue the project on another pc, so I loaded all on GitHub, in the end I downloaded it to another PC with python 3.11 installed, the files are all there but when I try, inside the virtual environment, to open python by writing `python` or `python3` in the terminal, it shows up this error: `Python not found; Run with no arguments to install from the Microsoft Store or disable the link from Settings > Manage apps Run aliases`.  I then tried to see if it only showed up inside the virtual environment, but the same thing happens outside as well.

I tried to do various things among those suggested in other forums but they didn't work, the problem persists, I'm a bit lost, it's the first time this has happened to me.

Sorry to bother, maybe it's the simplest problem there is to solve but I don't know where to start

Trhanks

Comment: seems the python directory wasn't added to PATH. You could check if it shows in your PATH directories

Comment: What does "the virtual environment" mean here? You have to have had Python working to create it in the first place ... unless you are trying to say you copied over the virtual environment's files from the other computer, too, which basically cannot be expected to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the different version of python on the two computers... the content of the pyvenv.cfg file must simply be changed which, when creating the virtual environment, is based on the installed version. Here you just need to change the path to reach the python.exe file installed on your computer and then change its version by inserting the correct one.